# How to analyze memory fragmentation in java?

Tags: java, memory-management

We experience several minutes lags in our server. Probably they are triggered by "stop the world" garbage collections. But we use concurrent mark and sweep GC (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepG) so, I think, these pauses are triggered by memory fragmentation of old generation.

How can memory fragmentation of old generation be analyzed? Are there any tools for it?

Lags happen every hour. Most time they are about 20 sec, but sometimes - several minutes.

Comment: Are you sure that it's GC? Especially, does the vm process show high CPU utilization during the pauses? If not, I'd assume you have a race condition somewhere.

Comment: It isn't a race condition, I'm sure. Checked in profiler, and we almost don't use locks, and behavior is the same at different servers - just different lag timings. And not a high CPU utilization - all the threads in app are stopped.

Comment: [Edited] After turning on GC logs I discovered "promotion failed" problem. Good description is here: http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/submitted/cms_gc_logs.html. Thank everybode for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your Java documentation for the "java -X..." options for turning on GC logging.  That will tell you whether you are collecting old or new generation, and how long the collections are taking.

A pause of "several minutes" sounds extraordinary.  Are you sure that you aren't just running with a heap size that is too small, or on a machine with not enough physical memory?

- If your heap too close to full,
  the GC will be triggered again and
  again, resulting in your server
  spending most of its CPU time in the
  GC.  This will show up in the GC
  logs.
- If you use a large heap on a machine
  with not enough physical memory,
  a full GC is liable to cause
  your machine to "thrash", spending
  most of its time madly moving virtual
  memory pages to and from disc.  You
  can observe this using system
  monitoring tools; e.g. by watching
  the console output from "vmstat 5" on
  a typical UNIX/Linux system.

**FOLLOWUP**

Contrary to the OP's belief, turning on GC logging is *unlikely* to make a noticeable difference to performance.

The [Understanding Concurrent Mark Sweep Garbage Collector Logs](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/submitted/cms_gc_logs.jsp) page on the Oracle site should be helpful in interpreting GC logs.

Finally, the OP's conclusion that this is a "fragmentation" problem is unlikely, and (IMO) unsupported by the snippets of evidence that he has provided.   It is most likely something else.

Comment: Several minutes lags happens to, once or two in a day. Edited a qustion.

Comment: Yes, I'll try verbose GC output. It just prints too much info - can slow down servers, wouldn't want to do it :) Now we use GarbageCollectorMXBeans. The output looks like this: ConcurrentMarkSweep 27459. And lag almost perfectly matches with it (27 sec). It happens every hour or so, that's why I think about memory fragmentation, not a memory leak. – Vitaly 0 secs ago  [delete this comment]

Answer (score 3):

For low-level monitoring you will want to use this `-XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1` (or make it 2 for more at more blocking cost) . It's undocumented and occasionally gives you some stats. Unfortunately it's not very useful in most applications for different reasons, but it's at least ballpark-useful.

You should be able to see for example

```
Max Chunk Size: 215599441
```

and compare it to this

```
Total Free Space: 219955840
```

and then judge the fragmentation based on the average block sizes and number of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [YourKit](http://yourkit.com) to good effect for this type of problem.

Comment: Yes, a great tool. But it doesn't show memory fragmentation - only memory consumption, which it doesn't help with lags. Or I don't know some cool options :)?

Comment: YourKit and other memory profilers will show you when / how frequently GC is happening to attempt to reorganize memory and reduce fragmentation.  It won't show you your fragmentation directly (unless I don't know about a cool option too)

Comment: I'm going to check behavior of GC through VisualVM. By the way, YourKit is dangerous to run at production servers. We had problems with performance even with an option "disable all". And thanks for advice about big objects.

Comment: What kind of performance problems did you see?  So far we have only used it in our stress test environment but had considered running it on one application server for a while to gather real-life metrics.

Comment: Lags :) If byte code instrumentation is turned on (default settings of agent), the lags are huge. If off, just lags.

Answer (score 0):

Vitaly, There is fragmentation problem. 
   My observation:
If there are small size of the objects which are getting updated frequently then in that case it generates lot of garbage. Though CMS collects the memory occupied by these objects, this memory is fragmented. Now Mark-Sweep-Compact thread comes into picture (stop the world)and try to compact this fragmented memory causing long pause.

Opposite to that if the objects size is bigger then it generates less fragmented memory and
Mark-Swap-Compact takes less time to compact this memory. This may cause less throughput but will help you to reduce the long pause caused by GC compaction.

Comment: We've already handled the problem. Sometimes there wasn't enough memory in oldgen to copy objects survived from young gen. Starting CMS when fixed amount memory consumed fixed the problem.

Comment: Vitaly, Can you please briefly point out the way you solved fragmentation problem?
   How exactly you triggered CMS after consuming fixed amount of money?And how this solve the fragmentation problem?

Kishor

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hard problem to find out. Since I had spend sometime in a system to find this out and prove, let me list out the scenario where this happened

- We were stuck with using Java 6 , which did not have any compacting Garbage collector
- Our application was doing too much GC mostly young generation collection and some big old generation collecition
- Our heap-size was pretty big- main problem ( we reduced, but our application was guzzling on too many strings and collections)

The problem that manifested was that only one particular algorithm in our system was running slow; the rest all which were running at the same time, was running quite normally. This ruled out Full GC ; Also we were using jstat and other j** tools to check GC, thread dumps + tailing the GC logs.

From jstack thread dumps , taken for some time, we could get an idea which code block was really slowing. So the doubt fell to heap fragmentation.

To test that I wrote a simple program that initialized two List one ArrayList and one LinkedList and did add operations causing resize. This test I could execute via REST handle.
Normally there is not much difference. But inside a fragmented heap there is a clear difference seen in timing; a big collection resize with ArrayList becomes very slow than with Linked list. These timings were logged, and there were no other explanation to this than a fragmented head.

With Java 7, we shifted to G1GC, along with lot of work in GC tuning and improving applications; Here heap compaction is much better and it can handle bigger heaps, though I guess anything over 16 g heap will land you in places you don't really want to go- GC suckage :)

Answer (score -1):

To see how Vitaly probably handled this, see [Understanding Concurrent Mark Sweep Garbage Collector Logs](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/submitted/cms_gc_logs.html).

Answer (score -4):

There is no memory fragmentation in Java; during the GC run, memory areas are compacted.

Since you don't see a high CPU utilization, there is no GC running, either. So something else must be the cause of your problems. Here are a few ideas:

- If the database of your application is on a different server, there may be network problems
- If you run Windows and you have mapped network drives, one of the drives may lock up your computer (again network problems). The same is true for NFS drives on Unix. Check the system log for network errors.
- Is the computer swapping lots of data to disk? Since CPU util is low, the cause of the problem could be that the app was swapped to disk and the GC run forced it back into RAM. This will take a long time if your server hasn't enough real RAM to keep the whole Java app in RAM.

Also, other processes can force the app out of RAM. Check the real memory utilization and your swap space usage.

To understand the output of the GC log, [this post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5352404) might help.

[EDIT] I still can't get my head around "low CPU" and "GC stalls". Those two usually contradict each other. If the GC is stalling, you must see 100% CPU usage. If the CPU is idle, then something else is blocking the GC. Do you have objects which overload `finalize()`? If a finalize blocks, the GC can take forever.

Comment: Well there IS fragmentation, but the GC will attempt to reduce it when it runs.  Having too many large-ish (relative to your available heap) objects that are frequently allocated/deallocated will cause the app to spend a lot of time in GC and harm performance.

Comment: There is a memory fragmentation if ConcurrentMarkAndSweep used. For example, http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rprf_javamemory.html.

Comment: Eric J., large objects sound as a great idea, thank you. I'll check memory dumps.

Comment: No, it is not network problems. Lags reported by GC matches lags in our internal log.

Comment: @Vitaly: Please give some more information how your app works. Is it creating huge HashMaps or something (i.e. large data graphs with lots of references to other objects) all the time?

Comment: Aaron, about CPU. By "not a high CPU utilization" I meant that all the threads are blocked and, so, it isn't our code who causing lags. CPU usage is high during the lags :))

Comment: @Aaron About hash maps. We have some HashMaps of size 20-30K elements (not sure if they are big). Also we create quite big byte[] quite often - they can be of size 40K-80K.

Comment: byte[] doesn't matter much for GC; for a GC, only object references matter. Do you add/remove elements from the HashMaps all the time?. As for "all threads are blocked", that should be "all threads but the GC thread". And the GC thread eats as much CPU as possible, so while it runs, you must have 100% CPU usage or something is odd.

Comment: Not all garbage collectors do compaction!  We use `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC` and we sometimes see

`191063.153: [GC 191063.153: [ParNew (promotion failed): 439755K->434641K(491008K), 0.9015529 secs]191064.055: [CMS: 657468K->382641K(1675264K), 7.5122632 secs] 1096285K->382641K(2166272K), [CMS Perm : 17482K->17417K(29160K)], 8.4145897 secs] [Times: user=9.18 sys=0.02, real=8.42 secs]
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 8.4295953 seconds`

Comment: With the CMS GC in Java 6, we have seen clear signs of heap fragmentation after some time, with frequent young and some Full GC happening. To test that I wrote a simple program that initialized two List one ArrayList and one LinkedList and did add operations causing resize. Normally there is not much difference. But inside a fragmented heap there is a clear difference seen. With Java 7, G1GC heap compaction is much better and it can handle bigger heaps