# can a java service bring down the hosting Unix box?

Tags: java, unix, out-of-memory, redhat

I was checking my Java service on a Redhat Unix box but only found that the box's SSH didn't work and  the SA explained that the machine ran out of memory and started consuming swap space, which eventually led the machine to hang and shutdown.

he implied that my java service bring down the server, I have hard time believing how this could be possible - as I think in the worst case scenario, the service will throw OutOfMemory exception and only crash itself.

my java memory setting is: "-Xms1g -Xmx5g" and from the /proc/meminfo it shows the box has

```
MemTotal:     16304084 kB
MemFree:      12288796 kB
```

A second question is, can we look into some log under /var/log to find out what's the real problem is?

Comment: @Greycon "You are correct, even if the JVM runs out of memory, it will not consume all of the host operating system memory" <-- err, that does remain a possibility; on a 64bit machine for instance you can very well specify that you want a max heap size of 5G even though the machine only has 4. The JVM doesn't care, and allocation failures will be dealt with by the OS

Comment: One thing to consider: set -Xms1g -Xmx5g to -Xms5g -Xmx5g or whatever is appropriate.  This helps to prevents heap fragmentation by allocating all of the memory on startup.  More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253388/how-to-analyze-memory-fragmentation-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can look in the log archives to see if the out of memory killer killed your or other processes while it was running out of memory (my log happens to be in /var/log/all.log, yours may be somewhere else and/or you should look at the log for the day this happened -- edit, on RedHat, this should be in `/var/log/messages`, but I don't know how they're rotated by default):

```
# grep -i -e "Killed process" -e "out of memory" /var/log/all.log
1406786406 1406786406 0 3 127.0.0.1 2014-07-31T01:00:06-05:00 ahostname kern err kernel[76729.082621]: [76729.082621] 
    Out of memory: Kill process 22407 (java) score 187 or sacrifice child
1406786406 1406786406 0 3 127.0.0.1 2014-07-31T01:00:06-05:00 ahostname kern err kernel[76729.082625]: [76729.082625]
    Killed process 22407 (java) total-vm:859680kB, anon-rss:304232kB, file-rss:608kB
1406811608 1406811608 0 3 127.0.0.1 2014-07-31T08:00:08-05:00 ahostname kern err kernel[101910.841683]: [101910.841683] 
    Out of memory: Kill process 1370 (java) score 198 or sacrifice child
1406811608 1406811608 0 3 127.0.0.1 2014-07-31T08:00:08-05:00 ahostname kern err kernel[101910.841686]: [101910.841686] 
    Killed process 1370 (java) total-vm:859928kB, anon-rss:332688kB, file-rss:560kB
```

To understand better what happens when a Linux system is out of memory, see the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html). Or just search for "out of memory killer".

What happens is that when the OS detects it's out of memory, it starts killing of processes. Sometimes this might end up being the `sshd` process or other critical ones for logging into the system.

Your Java process alone probably didn't cause the outage, but it likely combined with other things running on the same server to cause the issue. But looking in the logs for OOM Killer is a good place to start.

It's also good to use `top` to see what other processes are running that are using the rest of the memory on the system. To sort by memory usage (highest memory first), type `M` after running `top`.