# Kubernetes Pod CPU Throttling after few (3-4) runs

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, eclipselink, cpu-usage

I am having a spring boot application with spring-kafka version 2.5.
Our application is containerized in Docker and deployed in Kubernetes cluster.
This consumer fetches a record and performs database aggregation where I am using EclipseLink as a persistence service and Oracle database.
I am publishing batches of 100k message to this consumer topic. What we are observing is for initial few batches CPU usage of application is below 500milli core. But after few runs, CPU spikes up to its limit 2000milli core and even it throttles for more 2000milli core. There is no change done in between runs which will increase cpu usage. And the only solution we figured out is to redeploy our application in order to reduce cpu usage and then again it behaves same way.

We have performed JVM profiling and couldn't found any issue at Memory or Garbage collection.
My CPU request is 1000milli core and CPU limit is set to 2000milli core.

Please help me in finding what could be the root cause of this weird cpu throttling issue after few runs.

Appreciate your time.
Please find attached screenshot of CPU usage dashboard which shows sudden spike after some time for CPU usage.

My suspect is some configuration required at Kubernetes level to resolve this issue.[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also post the screenshot of Memory usage dashboard? If possible, with the same time series than the CPU image.

Comment: @emi Added the screenshot of Memory Usage Dashboard as well for the same time period.

Comment: There is another metric that could help, if there is any: the swap memory (post it if there is any). Another thing that may be happening is memory fragmentation, which would need to debug the application. One possible culprit maybe [a big `-Xms` and `-Xmx` exceeding the container’s memory limit](https://deliveroo.engineering/2019/01/08/how-to-debug-memory-usage-of-a-jvm-based-application.html#final-thoughts). Some other tips may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253388/how-to-analyze-memory-fragmentation-in-java).

Comment: It looks like you have a limit at 400MB and your app is hitting it, which forces the GC to run most of the time. What happens if you raise the container memory limit? Does it makes the same crazy CPU when running in local (dev) with the same memory limit?

Comment: We don't have swap memory metric as of now in grafana dashboard but will try to add it as well.. My request and limit of memory is set to 1Gi, -Xmx is set to 626M. 
So I don't think it is reaching its limit. (I have not set -Xms just fyi)..

Comment: From local there are few variables like I am using H2 database, and kafka is in my local machine itself. Hence I could not do apple to apple comparison in local machine.

Comment: Have you tried increasing container request and limit of memory, and also `-Xmx` (something like double it) ? If that  delays the appearance of the error, or eliminates it completely, you'll have the culprit.

Comment: How are you measuring your CPU throttling? You didn't include it in your post. If you're still seeing throttling in your application I suggest you to read kubernetes cpu limit implementation. This post has some good answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099425/pod-cpu-throttling